# PHP Email headers? Mime mistakes or something else...help to understand?

Tags: php, html, email, mime-types

I'm a junior in php. Now I trying to send some attachments throught php mail(), But when I'm going to read the mail, it displays (see down here) only in the text form. Also the attachments content is blank. I use an mail form found on internet. I think the error is with the /r/n or /n and things like that. Sorry for bed english. I can explain more if asked, await for your help! Sorry for too much code posting but i think it's neccesary to understand...

**THE FORM**

```
<form action="mailme.php"  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
-+-+-  other inputs and select -+-+-

<input name="upload[]" type="file">
<input name="upload[]" type="file">

...other file attachments like that above
</form>
```

**PHP**

```
Retrive variables and then 
$headers ="From: ".$SenderName." <".$from.">\n";

// boundary 
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

// headers for attachment 
    $headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .   "
                 boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\""; 

// multipart boundary 
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . "--{$mime_boundary}\n"
               . "Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
                 "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . $message . "\n\n"; 
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

// preparing attachments
    for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
            $file = fopen($files[$x],"rb");
            $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]));
            fclose($file);
            $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
            $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" .  

                        " name=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
            "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]\"\n" . 
            "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
            $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
    }

    // send

    $success = @mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers); 
    if ($success) { 
            echo "<p>mail sent to $to!</p>"; 
    } else { 
            print_r($files);
echo "<p>mail could not be sent!</p>".$from.'<br>'.$message.'<br>'.$to.'<br>'.$subject.'<br>'.$SenderName; 
    }
```

**THE OUTPUT**

```
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;

boundary="==Multipart_Boundary_x553132b5cf2c4c84ecdbd3285b8b590dx"

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

--==Multipart_Boundary_x553132b5cf2c4c84ecdbd3285b8b590dx
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Message <b>with<b> some <a href="html">html</a>!

--==Multipart_Boundary_x9351bff6284cb1fc967281cfede5762cx
Content-Type: {"application/octet-stream"};
name=""
Content-Disposition: attachment;
filename=""
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64

.....BLANK CONTENT! LIKE NO IMAGE WAS ATTACHED......    


--==Multipart_Boundary_x553132b5cf2c4c84ecdbd3285b8b590dx
```

Comment: No ideas? Another tuturial or somthing else to send an email with multiple attachments? Maybe the form style is wrong...

Comment: where does `$files` come from?

Comment: Sorry for delay $files = $_FILES["upload"];

Comment: It's right? or i must use another thing?

Answer (score 0):

use `var_dump($files);` to display what it contains. It [should contain an array](http://de3.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php) for every uploaded file, with name, type, size, tmp_name and error (if an error occured)

so your loop should look like this:

```
for($x=0;$x<count($files);$x++){
        $file = fopen($files[$x]['tmp_name'],"rb");
        //                      ^ path to the uploaded file
        $data = fread($file,filesize($files[$x]['tmp_name']));
        fclose($file);
        $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));
        $message .= "Content-Type: {\"application/octet-stream\"};\n" .  

                    " name=\"$files[$x]['name']\"\n" . 
        //                              ^ filename
        "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . " filename=\"$files[$x]['name']\"\n" . 
        "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . $data . "\n\n";
        $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";
}
```

You could also use `$files[$x]['type']` for the content-type, but I wouldn't trust what the uploading browser provides.